# Routing nested tabs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have:

```
-tab1
-tab2
-tab3
-- subtab1
-- subtab2 
-- subtab3
-- subtab4
- tab4
```

If i get to any subtab through the slide menu, the `tab3` becomes disabled.
I would like to force `tab3` to be enabled cause is the index of all the subtabs.
If i access subtabs from `tab3` everything works fine. But if i directley access any subtab (without clicking on `tab3`...) `tab3` becomes disabled.
Please note that `tab3` and all the subtabs have the same routing tab id `'tab6'`.

How can i change `tab3` to be enabled if i get on any subtab indirectly?

This is the APP: https://creator.ionic.io/share/2d9b0126751e

Part of relevant code:

```
.state('men.inicio', {
    url: '/inicio',
    views: {
      'tab1': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/inicio.html',
        controller: 'inicioCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('men.calculadora', {
    url: '/calculadora',
    views: {
      'tab6': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/calculadora.html',
        controller: 'calculadoraCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('men.contacto', {
    url: '/contacto',
    views: {
      'tab3': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/contacto.html',
        controller: 'contactoCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('men', {
    url: '/menu',
    templateUrl: 'templates/men.html',
    abstract:true
  })

  .state('men.diseOWeb', {
    url: '/disenoweb',
    views: {
      'tab6': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/diseOWeb.html',
        controller: 'diseOWebCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('men.desarrolloApp', {
    url: '/app',
    views: {
      'tab6': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/desarrolloApp.html',
        controller: 'desarrolloAppCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('men.blogCompleto', {
    url: '/blog',
    views: {
      'tab6': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/blogCompleto.html',
        controller: 'blogCompletoCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Thanks,

Comment: you can use somehow `state.includes('tab3')`

Comment: Where sould i put that? i'm on Ionic Creator, i can access controller, JS...